# Calling convention in Alamorefire, Alamore.request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, calling-convention

I'm new to Swift, from [Alamorefire Referencee](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/1.2.0/index.html), you can do the following to make a request

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
```

At first, I think `Alamorefire` is a class which has the class method name `request`. However, I am wrong, `Alamorefire.swift` is the source file containing methods. I love the way it does. However, before using this kind of calling convention, I want to know :

1. Is the calling convention popular in Swift .
2. I notice that we do not have any properties in `Alamorefire.swift`. What is the benefit of it vs creating an actual class or a wrapper which contains same methods and also you can add properties

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify know what you mean: what I think you're saying is "I checked the source code of Alamofire, and was expecting a public class or struct with methods in it. Instead, I found public functions not contained by any class or struct. Is this common? What is the benefit of it?".

If you look closer at the source code found in [Alamofire.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift), you can tell that most (if not all) functions in there delegate to `Manager.sharedInstance`, which can be found in [Manager.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Manager.swift). So there's the class you were looking for.

I believe the functions found in `Alamofire.swift` are to be considered helper functions, they only delegate to existing functionality. The authors of Alamofire probably thought it was unnecessary to wrap those functions with a class and make them static, and instead just let Swift's module namespacing do it's thing.

Is this a common pattern? Could be. I don't know. :)